# Where to store total of all records?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

On the home page of my Rails project management app I would like to show the total of all the `projects` ever created with the app.

This is quite easy to achieve. Right now, I am just doing:

```
<p>Total projects: <%= Project.count %></p>
```

However, I don't like the fact that the database gets hit every time a user views the home page.

Is there a more efficient way to store the project total, e.g. in a variable or a file?

By the way, there's no need for the count to be overly precise. I just want to use it for marketing purposes.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

in you application controller:

```
def project_count
  Rails.cache.fetch('project_count') {  Project.count }
end

helper_method :project_count
```

In your view:

```
<%= project_count %>
```

[Check doc](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/Cache/Store.html#method-i-fetch) for expiration etc

Comment: you'll probably want to deal with cache invalidation at some point, or use the `expires_in` option.